# create a subclass of NSView to enable setTag()

Tags: macos, xamarin, nsview, xamarin.mac

I am using xamarin to develop a Mac app, and somewhere in my program I want to set the tag of a NSView. However, the tag property is readonly for NSView, so I'm searching for a way to create a subclass where tag is writable. Is there any suggestion about how I should write the subclass? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyNSView : NSView
{
    public nint _tag;

    public new nint Tag
    {
        get
        {
            return _tag;
        }
        set
        {
            _tag = value;
        }
    }
```

Be aware that this is not longer the `NSView` Tag.

Using your custom `NSView` Tag

```
var view = new MyNSView ();

view.Tag = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to get `viewWithTag` working:

```
@IBInspectable
override var tag: Int {
    get { return super.tag  }
    set { super.tag = newValue } 
}
```

In IB the NSView's Tag is still greyed out, but there is also a subclass's Tag available for setting a value.

Still, to my best effort, I can't find a logical reason for Tag to be greyed out in IB.