# swift3 MacOS set Tag in subclass of NSView

Tags: swift3, tags, nsview

I have a sublass Abszisse of NSView. It works as expected, but I can't set a tag for it, neither programmatically nor in the storyboard where the default value of -1 is grayed out.

```
class Abszisse: NSView{
override var tag = 0
...
```

The error is `Cannot override with a stored property 'tag'`

The docs say to redefine the property as readonly, but I can't find anything how to do that. Might be very simple. In Objective-C that was not a problem.
Is there another possibility than in the answer of apineda in 
[create a subclass of NSView to enable setTag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377881/create-a-subclass-of-nsview-to-enable-settag])

Comment: See my message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377881/create-a-subclass-of-nsview-to-enable-settag/51529788#51529788. This is probably what you are after

Answer (score 4):

In Swift you can't directly override the permissions of a property, but you can do whatever you like in custom-defined setters and getters:

Swift 4.0

```
var _tag = -1
override var tag: Int {
    get {
        return _tag
    }
    set {
        _tag = newValue
    }
}
```

Note: `_tag` is just a variable name that implies privateness, but it could be any other name you like and doesn't have to have an underscore at the beginning.